# Chrome extension/app write and read from local directory without user interaction

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I'm developing a management app and extension and what I need to do now is manage a local directory in Chrome OS. I will download/edit/remove by server.

I've tried to use API **localStorage**, but it prompts the user to select directory.

I've also tried the **downloads** API, I can download the files and delete them, but I can't edit or see what's in the directory.

Is there any other way I can do it?

Thanks

Comment: Check the [File API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi)?

Comment: What I know about this API is that it requires user interaction, Am I wrong?

Comment: What is the problem with user consent? Being able to bypass it would be a security issue.

Comment: Decause the administrator is supposed to do everything remotely, but ok,  I understand it would be a security issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user needs to select the directory once and you need to have `{"fileSystem":["write","directory","retainEntries"]}` permission in the manifest. The directory only needs to be selected once. There is no workaround for this.